# Returning 2D NDArray in Pandas DataFrame.apply

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to `apply` a function along a `DataFrames`'s rows (using `apply` with `axis=1`). The function returns an NDArray with 2 dimensions. I would like the return of the `apply` to be a single object column that happens to contain 2D NDArrays but instead I get:

```
<venv>/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.pyc in _homogenize(data, index, dtype)
   5544                 v = lib.fast_multiget(v, oindex.values, default=NA)
   5545             v = _sanitize_array(v, index, dtype=dtype, copy=False,
-> 5546                                 raise_cast_failure=False)
   5547 
   5548         homogenized.append(v)

<venv>/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.pyc in _sanitize_array(data, index, dtype, copy, raise_cast_failure)
   2918     elif subarr.ndim > 1:
   2919         if isinstance(data, np.ndarray):
-> 2920             raise Exception('Data must be 1-dimensional')
   2921         else:
   2922             subarr = _asarray_tuplesafe(data, dtype=dtype)

Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional
```

Is there any way to tell Pandas to not try to unwrap the array?

UPDATE with Example:

```
arr = np.ones((3,3))
pd.DataFrame({'d': [arr, arr]}).apply(lambda x: x.ix['d'], axis=1)
```

Comment: can you add a sample data set, definition of your function and desired data set to your post?

Comment: `df.ix['d']` produces an error - it's not clear what do you want to achieve (what is the desired DF / data set)?

Comment: Right this is applying row-wise to passed in to the lambda is a Series corresponding to the row where the index of the Series is the column names,

Comment: It's still not clear what are you after... Your DF has one element (an array (3x3)) in each row.

Answer (score 1):

running `apply` on a series and filling it with multi-dimensional objects works fine

```
pd.Series([1, 2]).apply(lambda x: np.array([[x, x], [x, x]]))

0    [[1, 1], [1, 1]]
1    [[2, 2], [2, 2]]
dtype: object
```

---

However, on a dataframe pandas is expecting the return value to be scalar or one dimensional

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2]])
```

This works

```
df.apply(lambda x: 1)

0    1
1    1
dtype: int64
```

And this

```
df.apply(lambda x: [1])

   0  1
0  1  1
```

And this

```
df.apply(lambda x: [1] * 2)

0    [1, 1]
1    [1, 1]
dtype: object
```

Notice that when we returned a list of length `1` it returned a dataframe, but when we returned a list of length greater than `1`, it reverted back to a series of lists.

***HOLDON!***
Let's double the length of `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2]] * 2)
```

And run the same thing

```
df.apply(lambda x: [1] * 2)

   0  1
0  0  0
1  0  0
```

Whoa!  Ok, so I ran the same exact thing on two different dataframes.  It appears that when the length of the return value matches the off dimension of the dataframe, pandas assumes to match up the return value with the off dimensions index.

We can over-ride this with `pd.Series` where pandas will forgo its interpretation and use the series index it was given.

```
df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series([1] * 5))

   0  1
0  1  1
1  1  1
2  1  1
3  1  1
4  1  1
```

---

So what about ndarray

This breaks

```
df.apply(lambda x: np.ones((3, 2)))
```

> ```
> Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional
> ```

This works but isn't what you want

```
df.apply(lambda x: np.ones((3, 2)).tolist())

0    [[1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0]]
1    [[1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0]]
dtype: object
```

---

## Solution

Instead, I'd rap a comprehension with a `pd.Series` with the passed index

```
f = lambda x: np.ones((3, 2))

pd.Series([f(c) for _, c in df.iteritems()], df.columns)

0    [[1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0]]
1    [[1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0]]
dtype: object
```

***Note:***

```
type(pd.Series([f(c) for _, c in df.iteritems()], df.columns).iloc[0])

numpy.ndarray
```